# How to reconcile TypeScript's `strictFunctionTypes` with React Router and Redux?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-router, react-router-redux, definitelytyped

TypeScript 2.6 [introduced `strictFunctionTypes`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/10/31/announcing-typescript-2-6/), and after upgrading, I can't seem to get Redux and React Router to play nice with it and each other. Thus, I'm wondering how best to define the types for a component that is both to be displayed on a certain route, and receive props from Redux.

The following is about how I've set up my application. There's a route like this:

```
<Route path="/some/path/with/:parameter" component={ConnectedComponent}/>
```

Then the component that I want to be displayed receives props from both Redux and React Router, which I've tried to capture in the following type signature:

```
class BareComponent extends React.Component<ReduxProps & RouteProps, ArbitraryState>
```

...where the Redux props are defined similar to the following:

```
interface StateProps { storeProperty: string; }
interface DispatchProps { dispatchCallback: () => void; }
type ReduxProps = StateProps & DispatchProps;
```

...and the router props somewhat like the following:

```
interface RouteParams { parameter: string }
type RouteProps = RouteComponentProps<RouteParams>;
```

(where `RouteComponentProps` is imported from `react-router-dom`)

The component that is passed to the router (via `Route` in the first code sample above) is created as follows:

```
const ConnectedComponent = connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, RouteProps, ArbitraryStateInterface>(mapStateToProps)(BareComponent);
```

Unfortunately, with `strictFunctionTypes`, this leads TypeScript to complain that `ConnectedComponent` is not assignable to the type React Router expects:

```
    TS2322: Type '{ path: "/some/path/with/:parameter"; component: ComponentClass<Pick<StatePr...' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Rea...'.
Type '{ path: "/some/path/with/:parameter"; component: ComponentClass<Pick<StatePr...' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<RouteProps>'.
  Types of property 'component' are incompatible.
    Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<StateProps & DispatchProps & RouteC...' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<RouteComponentProps<any> | undefined> | ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any...'.
      Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<StateProps & DispatchProps & RouteC...' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any> | undefined>'.
        Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Type 'RouteComponentProps<any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Pick<StateProps & DispatchProps & RouteComponentProps<R...'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Pick<StateProps & DispatchProps & RouteComponentProps<R...'.
              Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Pick<StateProps & DispatchProps & RouteComponentProps<R...'.
```

So, what in the way I'm defining the types above is not in line with how the types are meant to be used? Is there a way for me to enable `strictFunctionTypes` without resorting to the use of `any`s?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `react-router-dom`'s `withRouter` HOC function in addition to the `connect` you're already using.
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Tip: Use `recompose` to keep things tidy (and also helps with strict typescript headaches I've found).

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
...

...
export const ConnectedComponent = compose<ReduxProps & RouteProps, void>(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    withRouter
)(BareComponent);
```

Replace 'void' with any props you want exposed.

That might be 95% of it. Don't have VPN access to double check at the moment. And I'm on my phone so sorry for shitty formatting. I'll update once I can check what's worked for me!

Comment: Hmm, so I dived into `withRouter` a bit more, but I don't think that solves my problem? As far as I can see, `withRouter` simply passes the router's props to the connected component, but doesn't `<Route>` (to which it is passed) do the same? Why would `<Route>` (or its type definitions) expect a component wrapped in `withRouter`?